# Can't see StepContent from MUI stepper, react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

**Title: Issue with Rendering Components in React `StepContent`**

Description:

I am facing an issue with rendering components in a React Stepper in my application. The Stepper has three steps - "Dispatchs", "Orders", and "Tenders". Each step is supposed to render a specific set of components. But there seems to a problem rendering stepContent 2 and 3

Here's a full version of my component structure:

```
import {
  Card,
  Container,
  Stack,
  Step,
  StepContent,
  StepLabel,
  Stepper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Typography
} from '@mui/material';

import { format, parseISO } from 'date-fns';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import NetworkRepository from 'src/app-utils/network_repository';
import Scrollbar from 'src/components/scrollbar';
import OrdersTableRow from '../../orders/order-table-row/order-table-row';
import { useOrderTableFormate } from '../../orders/use-order-table-formate';
import TenderTableRow from '../../tender/tender-table-row/tender-table-row';
import { useTenderTableFormat } from '../../tender/use-tender-table-formate';
import DispatchTableRow from '../dispatches-table-row/dispatch-table-row';
import { useDispatchesTableFormat } from '../use-dispatches-table-formate';

export default function LoadingInstructionDetails() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loadingInstructionDetailsData, setLoadingInstructionDetailsData] = useState({});
  const [tenderDetailsData, setTenderDetailsData] = useState([]);
  const [tenderOrderData, setTenderOrderData] = useState();
  const { getStatusText, formatQty, formatQuantity, orderHeaderRow } = useOrderTableFormate();
  const { generateLocation, formatPrice, getPropertyValue, tenderHeaderRow } = useTenderTableFormat();

  const { loadingInstructionHeaderRow } = useDispatchesTableFormat();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const loadingInstructionDetails = await NetworkRepository.loadingInstructionDetails(id);
        setLoadingInstructionDetailsData(loadingInstructionDetails);

        // Create an array to store promises for fetching tenderDetails and orderDetails
        const detailsPromises = loadingInstructionDetails.loadinginstruction.map(async (loadinginstruction) => {
          const tenderDetails = await NetworkRepository.tenderDetails(loadinginstruction.order_head.tender_head.id);
          const orderDetails = await NetworkRepository.tenderOrder(loadinginstruction.order_head.tender_head.id);
          console.log(' { loadinginstruction, tenderDetails, orderDetails }', { loadinginstruction, tenderDetails, orderDetails })
          return { loadinginstruction, tenderDetails, orderDetails };
        });

        // Wait for all promises to resolve
        const detailsResults = await Promise.all(detailsPromises);

        // Extract the results and update state
        const tenderDetails = detailsResults.map(result => result.tenderDetails);
        const orderDetailsData = detailsResults.map(result => result.orderDetails);

        console.log('tenderDetails dfdsf', tenderDetails)

        setTenderDetailsData(tenderDetails);
        setTenderOrderData(orderDetailsData);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching Dispatch data:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchDetails();
  }, [id]);

  console.log('tenderOrderData', tenderDetailsData)

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xl">
      <Typography
        sx={{
          paddingTop: '12px',
          paddingBottom: '20px',
          paddingRight: '20px',
        }}
        variant="h4"
      >
        Dispatch Summary
      </Typography>

      {loadingInstructionDetailsData && loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction ? (
        <Stack spacing={2} >
          <Stepper orientation="vertical">
            <Step>
              <StepLabel><Typography variant='h6'>Dispatchs</Typography></StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                  <Scrollbar>
                    <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: 'unset' }}>
                      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                        <TableHead >
                          <TableRow>
                            {loadingInstructionHeaderRow.map((label, index) => (
                              <TableCell key={index} sx={{ height: '40px' }}>
                                {label.label}
                              </TableCell>
                            ))}
                          </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                          {
                            loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction.map((loadinginstruction, index) => (
                              <DispatchTableRow
                                orderNo={loadinginstruction.id}
                                invoiceNo={loadinginstruction.lr_number}
                                millName={loadingInstructionDetailsData.mill}
                                name={loadingInstructionDetailsData.trader}
                                date={format(parseISO(loadinginstruction.date), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}
                                vehicleNumber={loadingInstructionDetailsData.vehicle_num}
                                quantity={loadingInstructionDetailsData.total_qty}
                                billedTo={`${loadinginstruction.billing_address.name}\n${loadingInstructionDetailsData.billing_gstin}\n${loadinginstruction.billing_address.address}`}
                                shipTo={`${loadinginstruction.address.name}\n${loadingInstructionDetailsData.address_gstin}\n${loadinginstruction.address.address}`}
                                rate={loadinginstruction.product != null ? loadinginstruction.order_head.price : 'Not given'}
                                grade={loadinginstruction.product != null ? loadinginstruction.product.code : 'Not given'}
                              />
                            ))
                          }
                        </TableBody>
                      </Table>
                    </TableContainer>
                  </Scrollbar>
                </Card>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel>
                <Typography variant='h6'>Orders</Typography>
              </StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
              {tenderOrderData ? (
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2, marginLeft: 4 }}>
                  <Scrollbar>
                    <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: 'unset' }}>
                      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                        <TableHead>
                          {orderHeaderRow.map((label, index) => (
                            <TableCell key={index} sx={{ height: '40px' }}>
                              {label.label}
                            </TableCell>
                          ))}
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                          {tenderOrderData.map((tenderOrder, index) => (
                            tenderOrder.results.map((result) => (
                              <OrdersTableRow
                                key={result.id}
                                ordersId={result.id}
                                traderName={result.trader.name}
                                millName={result.tender_head.mill.name}
                                date={format(parseISO(result.date), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}
                                price={`₹ ${result.price} ${result.tender_head.product.product_type.unit}`}
                                status={getStatusText(result.status)}
                                tenderType={result.tender_head.tender_type}
                                productType={result.tender_head.product.product_type.product_type}
                                grade={
                                  result.tender_head.product.properties.length > 0
                                    ? result.tender_head.product.properties[0].label
                                    : 'Not given'
                                }
                                season={
                                  result.tender_head.product.properties.length > 0
                                    ? result.tender_head.product.properties[0].value
                                    : 'Not given'
                                }
                                sale={formatQty(result.qty)}
                                loading={`${formatQuantity(
                                  result,
                                  'yet_to_load',
                                  result.yet_to_load
                                )} ${result.tender_head.product.product_type.unit}`}
                                dispatched={`${formatQuantity(
                                  result,
                                  'dispatched_qty',
                                  result.yet_to_load
                                )} ${result.tender_head.product.product_type.unit}`}
                                balance={`${formatQuantity(
                                  result,
                                  'available_qty',
                                  result.yet_to_load
                                )} ${result.tender_head.product.product_type.unit}`}
                                order={result.tender_head}
                              />
                            ))))}
                        </TableBody>
                      </Table>
                    </TableContainer>
                  </Scrollbar>
                </Card>
              ) : (<Typography variant="subtitle1" marginLeft={4} paddingTop={4}>This Dispatch has no orders</Typography>)}
            </StepContent>
            </Step>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel><Typography variant='h6'>Tenders</Typography></StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
              <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2, marginLeft: 4 }}>
                <Scrollbar>
                  <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: 'unset' }}>
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                      <TableHead >
                        <TableRow>
                          {tenderHeaderRow.map((label, index) => (
                            <TableCell key={index} sx={{ height: '40px' }}>
                              {label.label}
                            </TableCell>
                          ))}
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {tenderDetailsData.map((tenderDetails) => (
                          <TenderTableRow
                            key={tenderDetails.id}
                            tenderId={tenderDetails.id}
                            name={tenderDetails.mill.name}
                            location={generateLocation(tenderDetails.mill.location, tenderDetails.mill.state.name)}
                            date={format(parseISO(tenderDetails.date), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}
                            price={formatPrice(tenderDetails.price, tenderDetails.product.product_type.unit)}
                            status={tenderDetails.status}
                            tenderType={tenderDetails.tender_type}
                            productType={tenderDetails.product.product_type.product_type}
                            grade={getPropertyValue(tenderDetails.product.properties, 0, 'label', 'Not given')}
                            season={getPropertyValue(tenderDetails.product.properties, 0, 'value', 'Not given')}
                            total={tenderDetails.qty}
                            sold={tenderDetails.approved_qty}
                            balance={tenderDetails.available_qty}
                          />
                        ))}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Scrollbar>
              </Card>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
          </Stepper>
        </Stack>
      ) : (
        <Typography variant="h10">Dispatch details data is null</Typography>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Content of the Stepper is not visible for the "Orders" and “Tenders” steps (Step 2 and 3).

What seems to be the problem? If I remove `StepContent` in step 2 and 3, I see the components, how do I fix it?

Here some additional info

**Minimal reproducible code as requested**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Card, Container, Stack, Step, StepContent, StepLabel, Stepper, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, Typography } from '@mui/material';

export default  MinimalDispatchDetails = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadingInstructionDetailsData, setLoadingInstructionDetailsData] = useState({ loadinginstruction: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      try {
        // Simulate fetching data
        const loadingInstructionDetails = { loadinginstruction: [...Array(3).keys()].map(index => ({ id: index })) };
        setLoadingInstructionDetailsData(loadingInstructionDetails);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching Dispatch data:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchDetails();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xl">
      <Typography variant="h4">Dispatch Summary</Typography>

      {loadingInstructionDetailsData && loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction ? (
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <Stepper orientation="vertical">
            <Step>
              <StepLabel>
                <Typography variant='h6'>Dispatchs</Typography>
              </StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                  <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: 'unset' }}>
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction.map((loadinginstruction, index) => (
                          <TableRow key={index}>
                            <TableCell>{loadinginstruction.id}</TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        ))}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Card>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel>
                <Typography variant='h6'>Order</Typography>
              </StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                  <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: 'unset' }}>
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction.map((loadinginstruction, index) => (
                          <TableRow key={index}>
                            <TableCell>{loadinginstruction.id}</TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        ))}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Card>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel>
                <Typography variant='h6'>Tender</Typography>
              </StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                  <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: 'unset' }}>
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction.map((loadinginstruction, index) => (
                          <TableRow key={index}>
                            <TableCell>{loadinginstruction.id}</TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        ))}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Card>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
          </Stepper>
        </Stack>
      ) : (
        <Typography variant="h10">Dispatch details data is null</Typography>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this? Probably on codesandbox?

Comment: Seems like your issue is not related to Mui Stepper.

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar I've added some reproducible code, hope it helps

Comment: @Illuminate I have posted solution, please do checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are not passing activeStep prop to Stepper, it doesn't know which step it needs to highlight.

By Default, activeStep's value is 0, that's why you can see Dispatch only.

## Solution

Used a activeStep state so that DispatchSummary Component remember which vertical step it is.
`<Stepper orientation="vertical" activeStep={activeStep}>`

DispatchSummary

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  Paper,
  Stack,
  Step,
  StepContent,
  StepLabel,
  Stepper,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { LoadingInstructionTable } from "./LoadingInstructionsTable";

export default DispatchSummary = () => {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [loadingInstructionDetailsData, setLoadingInstructionDetailsData] =
    useState({ loadingInstructions: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const loadingInstructions = [...Array(4).keys()].map((index) => ({
          id: index,
        }));
        setLoadingInstructionDetailsData({ loadingInstructions });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching Dispatch data:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchDetails();
  }, []);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  const steps = ["Dispatchs", "Order", "Tender"];

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xl">
      <Typography variant="h4">Dispatch Summary</Typography>
      {loadingInstructionDetailsData?.loadingInstructions && (
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <Stepper orientation="vertical" activeStep={activeStep}>
            {steps.map((step, index) => (
              <Step key={index}>
                <StepLabel>
                  <Typography variant="h6">{step}</Typography>
                </StepLabel>
                <StepContent>
                  <LoadingInstructionTable
                    loadingInstructions={
                      loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadingInstructions
                    }
                  />
                  <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                    <Button onClick={handleNext} variant="contained">
                      Next
                    </Button>
                  </Stack>
                </StepContent>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
        </Stack>
      )}
      {activeStep === steps.length && (
        <Paper square elevation={0} sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleReset} sx={{ mt: 1, mr: 1 }}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Paper>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

LoadingInstructionsTable

```
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Card,
} from "@mui/material";

export const LoadingInstructionTable = ({ loadingInstructions }) => (
  <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
    <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: "unset" }}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {loadingInstructions.map((loadingInstruction, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell>{loadingInstruction.id}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </Card>
);
```

If you wanna play around with the [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/thirsty-rgb-ptx4q8?file=%2Fsrc%2FDispatchSummary.js%3A7%2C8).

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped get more insight. We can make each step active

Answer (score 1):

Stepper component shows only 1 step at a time. You will have to toggle between the steps. This can be achieved by indicating which step is currently active.

The Stepper component takes `activeStep` as prop in which you can mention which step is currently active. NOTE: The steps start with index 0.

I declared the following states:

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
const lastStepIndex = 2;
```

I added a Button component to toggle between steps.

Also is there any reason why you wan to show all the steps at the same time?

Your reproducible code with updated logic:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  Container,
  Stack,
  Step,
  StepContent,
  StepLabel,
  Stepper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Typography,
  Button,
} from "@mui/material";

export default App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadingInstructionDetailsData, setLoadingInstructionDetailsData] =
    useState({ loadinginstruction: [] });
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const lastStepIndex = 2;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDetails = async () => {
      try {
        // Simulate fetching data
        const loadingInstructionDetails = {
          loadinginstruction: [...Array(3).keys()].map((index) => ({
            id: index,
          })),
        };
        setLoadingInstructionDetailsData(loadingInstructionDetails);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching Dispatch data:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchDetails();
  }, []);

  const handleStepChange = () => {
    setActiveStep((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="xl">
      <Typography variant="h4">Dispatch Summary</Typography>

      {loadingInstructionDetailsData &&
      loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction ? (
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <Stepper orientation="vertical" activeStep={activeStep}>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel>
                <Typography variant="h6">Dispatchs</Typography>
              </StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                  <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: "unset" }}>
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction.map(
                          (loadinginstruction, index) => (
                            <TableRow key={index}>
                              <TableCell>{loadinginstruction.id}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          )
                        )}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Card>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  style={{
                    marginTop: "10px",
                  }}
                  onClick={handleStepChange}
                >
                  {activeStep === lastStepIndex ? "Finish" : "Continue"}
                </Button>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel>
                <Typography variant="h6">Order</Typography>
              </StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                  <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: "unset" }}>
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction.map(
                          (loadinginstruction, index) => (
                            <TableRow key={index}>
                              <TableCell>{loadinginstruction.id}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          )
                        )}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Card>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  style={{
                    marginTop: "10px",
                  }}
                  onClick={handleStepChange}
                >
                  {activeStep === lastStepIndex ? "Finish" : "Continue"}
                </Button>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
            <Step>
              <StepLabel>
                <Typography variant="h6">Tender</Typography>
              </StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <Card sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
                  <TableContainer sx={{ overflow: "unset" }}>
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
                      <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                      </TableHead>
                      <TableBody>
                        {loadingInstructionDetailsData.loadinginstruction.map(
                          (loadinginstruction, index) => (
                            <TableRow key={index}>
                              <TableCell>{loadinginstruction.id}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                          )
                        )}
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                  </TableContainer>
                </Card>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  style={{
                    marginTop: "10px",
                  }}
                  onClick={handleStepChange}
                >
                  {activeStep === lastStepIndex ? "Finish" : "Continue"}
                </Button>
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
          </Stepper>
        </Stack>
      ) : (
        <Typography variant="h10">Dispatch details data is null</Typography>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

You can see this example too: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/#vertical-stepper

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing issues with connector lines in a multi-step process and you want to make each step active, the solution involves using the active and expanded props on each  component. Here's an example:

```
<Step active expanded>
  {/* Step content */}
</Step>
```

This usage of active and expanded on each  helps to visually indicate the active state of each step and resolve any issues with connector lines.